# How can I detect if a smartcard is still in the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, smartcard

We use smart cards in Dell keyboards for authentication at work. Unfortunately they are also the badges that let us into our offices (and other places).  Being old, we are constantly forgetting our badges in the keyboard and getting locked out of our offices.  Very annoying!!

Is it possible to detect if the badge is still in the keyboard when we leave our office?

I can write a small program and hook up a sensor to detect if we are in our offices but I need to be able to access something in the computer that tells me if the badge is in the keyboard.   Can anyone tell me what that "something" is in "Windows 7 Pro" and how to access it?

I have novice level skills with things like Arduino, Basic (not visual) and Python, but am not even remotely close to the level of a professional programmer.

We have tried lots of things. We even set up a laser beam that sounds an alarm when broken, but when we are concentrating, we tune out the alarm because it goes off every time we get up and we get used to it.  I think the key is to identify when the badge is in the keyboard and then work with that datum.  And we may not modify the badge in anyway so we can't tie a string to it like we wanted to.

Comment: How about a lanyard?

Comment: "Is it possible to detect if the badge is still in the keyboard when we leave our office?" - Yes;  It is possible to detect if a Smart Card is inserted into a Smart Card Reader.  Except you cannot do it with Arduino, Basic, or Python.  I presume since your using the smart card to authenticate your session on your computer, that it also will automatically locked your session, that makes any solution extremely difficult.  Any software solution, would require you to be at your desk to be notified of the status, which is where the smart card is located.

Comment: @CharlieRB The badge is in a RFID shield on the lanyard. We have to take the badge out to use it. Nothing may be attached to the badge itself.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes that won't be a problem because it is when we leave our desks that the problem occurs because without a badge we can't come back. So I can easily detect if we leave the office. But I don't know how to get the info of whether the card is in the reader in the instant that my Arduino detects that we are in the processing of leaving. So screen lock is a nonissue for us. –

Comment: @Mikech - We cannot tell you how to do it.  That is out of scope, and far more involved, if you don't have the programming expertise to do it yourself.

Comment: @Ramhound - I don't need help with programming.  I can almost always figure that part out myself.  I only asked because  I don't know where to start. I just need to know where on the computer, or which program or service will have the keyboard smartcard status.  I will try to figure the rest out myself. I also don't have patience with people wanting programs written for them.  Half the fun is figuring it out.  I got started in the early 70s programming gamma spectrometers in machine language flipping toggle switches, so while I don't know a lot of the modern windows stuff I am no neophyte.

Answer (score 0):

I am withdrawing this question as I was able to figure it out by myself eventually (sort of) quite by sheer luck. While looking for something else I stumbled across a program called "ActiveClient" which knows whether the badge is inserted or not. Now that I know where the information is on the computer I will figure out how to write the software myself (since that is not what I was asking for help with).  Also I suspect that software is getting its information from a service called "SCardSvr" and I only need to research how to access the output of this service.